# Python folium markercluster doesn't work as expected for the add_child element

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I would like to clusterize my points. Unfortunately I cannot do it with my code it loos like.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import folium
 from folium import FeatureGroup
 from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

 map = folium.Map(location=[51.86762,0.8624], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=8)

 mCluster = MarkerCluster(control = False).add_to(map)

 fc=folium.FeatureGroup(name="CF",overlay=True)
 df = pd.read_csv("cf_geo.csv")
 for i,row in df.iterrows():
 lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
 lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
 sp = df.at[i, 'sp']

 popup = df.at[i,'sp'] +'<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'street']) + '<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'post code'])
 fc.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], popup=popup, icon = 
 folium.Icon(color='green')))
 mCluster.add_child(fc)
```

All my items are gone.

I tried these hints:

https://splunktool.com/how-to-add-a-marker-manually-or-with-draw-plugin-folium-python-and-be-able-to-export-it-or-save-it

and other, general sources show rather the most simple way:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7HUBNmXB5Y&ab_channel=LearningSoftwareSkills

How to add Cluster markers to Choropleth with Folium

How can I make the makrercluster working for the child elements of the folium library?

Answer (score 2):

The right track for this problem is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222835/folium-put-markers-in-marker-clusters-and-in-layers-based-on-a-value

In turn, my code should look like this:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("cf_geo.csv")
 fc=folium.FeatureGroup(name="CF",overlay=True)  
 cf_cluster = MarkerCluster(name="CF").add_to(map)  
 for i,row in df.iterrows():
 lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
 lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
 sp = df.at[i, 'sp']

 popup = df.at[i,'sp'] +'<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'street']) + '<br>' + str(df.at[i, 
 'post code'])
 cf_marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], popup=popup, icon = 
 folium.Icon(color='green'))
 cf_cluster.add_child(cf_marker)
```

where we need to do 3 steps:

1. Define your own cluster for the particular layer **instead of the general definition in my previous code above**.

   ```
   cf_cluster = MarkerCluster(name="CF").add_to(map)
   ```
2. Define the individual variable for the marker, representing just items from the particular layer, **unlike classifying this marker as the child to append to the main map**.

   ```
    cf_marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], popup=popup, icon =
   ```

   folium.Icon(color='green'))
3. Append this marker as the child of the cluster defined earlier.

   ```
     cf_cluster.add_child(cf_marker)
   ```